# Compatibility of android annotations with Kotlin 1.6.0

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

I have noticed that due to changes in Kotlin : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compatibility-guide-16.html#annotation-target-is-not-analyzed-in-several-cases-for-annotations-on-a-type
a lot of androidx annotations (@StringRes, @DrawableRes etc) have been reported as errors because of "type usage". E.g. MutableLiveData<@StringRes Int> . Does anybody knows does Google plans to update Tragets of those annotations or it is me who is using them in wrong way?
Solution given by jetbrains to disable error reporting is working, however it is not correct way to deal with it.

Comment: Found issue on tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209843426

Comment: Let me know if you ever find an answer to this..

Comment: the linked google issue tracker has a solution of adding a compiler flag.  That seemed to have fixed it for me.

Comment: Yeah, it works but this is for sure not correct approach. This is workaround for annotations which should be supported