# Gradle Kotlin DSL and freeCompilerArgs

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

On one project I have used sucesfully argument `-XXLanguage:-ProperCheckAnnotationsTargetInTypeUsePositions` in kotlinOptions to disable "typeUsage" check on annotations. This project has regular build.gradle in Groovy. However when I have used exactly same approach on same version of Kotlin (1.6.0) in fresh project with Kotlin DSL gradle files (build.gradle.kts) it seems like this argument is ignored totally.

Summarizing:

- project with good-old Groovy gradle -> argument works and disable error on "wrong usage of annotations"
- project with new Kotlin DSL gradle -> argument seems to be ignored and still produces error

Maybe someone has same issue?
This is connected with [Compatibility of android annotations with Kotlin 1.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494004/compatibility-of-android-annotations-with-kotlin-1-6-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
    freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-XXLanguage:-ProperCheckAnnotationsTargetInTypeUsePositions")
}
```